# Laravel query builder doesn't work with where clause in subquery

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I have a query like this:

```
$q = \DB::table(\DB::raw('('.
    \DB::table('table1')
         ->where('field1', 1)->toSQL()
.') AS rs'));

dd($q->get()); // return []
```

Despite why I have to use this approach, when I remove the `where` clause it returns all the records correctly, but nothing when using `where()`.

I'm sure that there is record when `field1 = 1`. If I use `$q->toSQL()` the final SQL is:

```
select * from (select * from table1 where field1 = ?) AS rs
```

When I paste this sql to phpmyadmin it returns 1 record. So it seems that Query builder causes this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself! I should use:

```
$q1 = Table1Model()::select()->where('field1', 1);

$q2 = \DB::table(\DB::raw('('.
    $q1->toSQL()
.') AS rs'))
->mergeBindings($q1->getQuery());
```